# How to upsert new records with DEFAULT as id to Postgres from node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm using NodeJS and pg with a PostgreSQL database for the backend. I'd like to upsert multiple rows to a table in a single statement, using id (which is BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL) to check if its a new record to insert rather than update.

If I create the query just passing the values in like this it works:

```
let upsertQuery = `INSERT INTO triage (id, col1, col2)
    VALUES (1, 'abc', 'def'), (DEFAULT, 'ghi', 'jkl')
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
      col1 = EXCLUDED.col1,
      col2 = EXCLUDED.col2`;
```

But if I use parameters to avoid SQL injection, like this:

```
let upsertQuery = `INSERT INTO triage (id, col1, col2)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3), ($4, $5, $6)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
      col1 = EXCLUDED.col1,
      col2 = EXCLUDED.col2`;

let values = [1, 'abc', 'def', 'DEFAULT', 'ghi', 'jkl']

 try {
    await pool.query(upsertQuery, values)
    res.status(201).json({message:'Updated'});
 }
 catch(err) {
    await pool.query('ROLLBACK');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
 }
```

The error is:

"name": "error",
"severity": "ERROR",
"code": "22P02",
"where": "unnamed portal parameter $4 = '...'",
"file": "numutils.c",
"routine": "pg_strtoint64"